# Picture and text in same window

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

This program is supposed to open a window, add a picture, and then add the text "hello world" above the picture. The text appears when i do frame.add(label) and then try to add the picture (like the code shows), but even when I do the opposite and add the picture first I only get a gray schreen. Can anybody show me how I can get both the picture and the text?

```
  public window(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("name");
    JLabel label = new JLabel ("hello world", JLabel.CENTER);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    label.setAlignmentX(0);
    label.setAlignmentY(0);
    frame.add(label);
    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("file")));;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) `new ImageIcon("file")` Is this image supplied by you or the user?  What is the exact file name? 2) `frame.setVisible(true);` This should be done last.  3) Adding two components (in this case) will result in only one being visible.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `overlay` layout, but it is applicable on `JPanel`.

So add a `JPanel` to your `frame` then apply the `layout`, finally add the `components`.

Your code may be like that:

```
public window(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("name");
    JLabel label = new JLabel ("hello world", JLabel.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
      public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
        return false;
      }
    };
    LayoutManager overlay = new OverlayLayout(panel);
    panel.setLayout(overlay);  
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    label.setAlignmentX(0);
    label.setAlignmentY(0);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("file"))); 
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A label can have both text and icon, and the relative position can be customized.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel ("hello world", new ImageIcon("file"), JLabel.CENTER);
label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
frame.add(label);
//frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("file")));;
```

The default layout is BorderLayout, and `add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER)`.